# How to return a bool where list only contains one or more of the values required

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling to work out how to return whether a list of items which only contains one or more of the required query params.

I thought a `TrueForAll` might work but if one of them doesn't exist then it returns false.

```
var hasValidOptions = entity.clientcodes.TrueForAll(x => x.code == "B"
                                                      || x.code == "C"
                                                      || x.code == "E"
                                                      || x.code == "G"))
```

Here's some examples of what I'm trying to do (I'm only concerned with B, C, E and G):

- List 1: `A B E G` -> false because it contains A
- List 2: `B G` -> true because it contains B and G
- List 3: `E` -> true as it contains E
- List 4: `B C E G` -> true as it contains B, C, E and G

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Your code does exactly what you described [see fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/qjaJF8)

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can use `All`:

```
list.All(x => x.code == "B" || x.code == "C" || x.code == "E" || x.code == "G");
```

You can make it easier to modify the options by using an array of them like:

```
string[] options = new [] { "B", "C", "E", "G" };
list.All(x => options.Contains(x.code));
```

Comment: If the number of options is more than a few elements, you may want to use a HashSet instead of an array as Contains is O(1) versus O(n).

Comment: I don't really get what the difference to the code in the question is. Shouldn't both `All` and `TrueForAll` do the exact same thing?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I believe `TrueForAll` needs all of the conditions to be true to return true so if the list doesn't contain a value it will return false, although I am not 100% on that.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Isn't it the same for `All`?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer All doesn't need all of the conditions to meet i.e. if the list doesn't contain a `B` it will still return true whereas I believe `TrueForAll` will return false in that case

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I dare say it's identical and OP's code should work: [see Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/qjaJF8)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer It does appear to be identical then, probably because the statements are OR'd and not separate, however both work as expected so the OP has either copied the code wrong or has not provided a test case that isn't working as expected

Answer (score -1):

Adjusted my code and it does exactly what I want now. If this can be improved happy to see any comments

I've simplified the example, the string array is built dynamically.

```
var clientCodes = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "E", "G"};

var hasValidOptionsOnly = clientCodes.TrueForAll(x=>x.Contains("B") || x.Contains("C") || x.Contains("E") || x.Contains("G"));
```

Now it returns true if the list only contains any combination of B, C, E or G

Comment: This is nonsense. Sorry, but that code, while it may work, doesn't make any sense! Why would you check if `"A"` **contains** `"A"`? Your original attempt and @TheLethalCoder 's answer are way better.

Comment: @ColinM Which according to the question and this answer it never is.

Comment: Exactly, @Codesight `Contains` makes no sense here and is less efficient than simply checking the equality of the string

Comment: Also it would lead to false positives. This code would return true for `{"WRONG", "FALSE", "BS", "NOPE!"}` because every item contains at least one of the *valid* characters.